Unable to Access Elasticsearch on http://localhost:9200 from Browser on macOS
I am trying to set up an Elasticsearch and Kibana stack using Docker on my macOS machine. While Kibana is accessible via http://localhost:5601, I am unable to access Elasticsearch via http://localhost:9200 from my browser. Here are the details of my setup and the steps I have taken:
docker compose file : 
version: '3.8'
services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: arm64v8/elasticsearch:7.13.4
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    image: arm64v8/kibana:7.13.4
    container_name: kibana
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    environment:
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200


volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local

macOs version : 13.0 (22A380)
docker desktop Version  : 4.30.0 (149282)
Kibana is accessible at http://localhost:5601
Elasticsearch is supposed to be accessible at http://localhost:9200 but it isn't.
Checked Firewall,
Verified Port Listening:
netstat shows that port 9200 is listening:
sh
netstat -an | grep 9200
tcp46      0      0  *.9200                 *.*                    LISTEN     

Used curl from Host:
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200 works and returns the expected JSON response.
Issue
Despite all checks indicating that Elasticsearch is running and accessible, I cannot access it via http://localhost:9200 from my browser. Kibana is accessible without any issues.

You should add this into your elasticsearch.yml file
network.host: 0.0.0.0

This will allow connection in local interface.
